# Getting "rawDestElement is undefined" using jQuery Plugin Quicksand

Tags: javascript, jquery, quicksand

I am using the [jQuery Quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand) -- http://jsfiddle.net/se9pY/

but I get `rawDestElement is undefined` in FireBug...

```
$(function() {
    $("#filter a").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
                $oriColl = $("#boxes"),
                $clonedColl = $oriColl.clone(),
                filtered = ($this.text() == "all") ? $("#boxes li") : $("#boxes li[data-type=" + $this.text() + "]");

        $("#boxes").quicksand(filtered, { duration: 800, easing: 'easeInOutQuad' });
    });
});
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this problem a while back, turned out to be a simple oversight. You probably figured this out by now, but you likely just need a unique data-id attribute on all list items.

```
<li data-type="test" data-id="id-1">...</li>
```